# Clone Wordpress Site Hosted on Heroku

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku

I have a Wordpress blog hosted on Heroku.

I'm trying to figure out how to clone the site from Heroku so that I can do my WP development locally (I've set up VVV locally - works like a dream).

I've tried backing up the Heroku site with WP Clone and it fails because Heroku's PHP install doesn't include zlib (I know how to install plugins and have installed and activated the WP Clone plugin, but it screams for zlib when attempting to backup).

I've tried WPManage and it can connect to the Heroku site, but when I try to backup I get a 500 internal server error.

Has anyone had success cloning, or backing up, a WP site and database that is hosted on Heroku? How? Different cloning tools to try?

Comment: Where is that error about missing zlib coming from? zlib is enabled in PHP on Heroku...

Comment: As far as I can ascertain, the current PHP Buildpack includes zlib. Unfortunately, the blog was deployed 3 years ago and at that time it was not included. I've found multiple tutorials on how to install zlib on the legacy PHP stack - I haven't been able to get one working, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do it manually if you planned to do it locally. XAMMP or WAMP?

Just backup your user data, images, plugin and database.

Comment: VVV set up locally for serving WP. Backing up the Heroku database seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A tool that I have good success with is [Duplicator.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) You're biggest issue is that your PHP config is missing required libs that wordpress needs to function properly.

I would look at getting a PHP install that has zlib in as wordpress itself uses it. See [What are PHP extensions and libraries WP needs and/or uses?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42212/3170)

Comment: My local install is fine. I'm limited on what I can do with the Heroku Cedar stack.

Comment: According to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support zlib is included and you can add extra modules with composer.json unless you're using HHVM.

Comment: See my comment above. This site was built on PHP 5.3.x in 2012.

Comment: Might be worth migrating to the new stack instead of attempting to get zlib into the legacy stack.

Comment: You are probably right about migrating to the new stack. I tried using Duplicator. It failed but gave me clues. Duplicator would not set up on Heroku and gave me the following errors: Zip Archive Enabled -- Fail, and MySQLi Support -- Fail. So I may have issues with Heroku implementing ClearDB vs mySQL as well.